# How to handle excel using OLE module?

Tags: perl, excel, automation, spreadsheet, ole

Friends, I wrote a Perl script to convert a set of CSV files into spreadsheet
format using [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.38/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm).  After some research I came to
conclusion that there is no option to fix column width as Auto-fit option.

So what I'm doing is in the same script I've opened that XLS file using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm)
module, while doing this I got an error message

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference
```

Corresponding code is:

```
# spread sheet creation
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($file_name);
# ...
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($work_sheet_name);
# ...
$worksheet->write($rowNum, $j,$_,$default_format);
```

after these steps I have some more lines in the same script:

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$Excel->{'Visible'} = 0;    #0 is hidden, 1 is visible
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=1;  #0 is hide alerts

# Open File and Worksheet
my $return_file_name="C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Report_Gen\\$file_name";
print ">>$return_file_name<<";
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open($return_file_name); # open Excel file
foreach my $Sheet (in $Book->Sheets) {
    my $LastCol = $Sheet->UsedRange->Find({What=>"*", 
        SearchDirection=>xlPrevious,
        SearchOrder=>xlByColumns})->{Column};    # mentioned error is from this line
    my $mylastcol = 'A';
    for (my $m=1;$m<$LastCol;$m++) {$mylastcol++;}
    my @columnheaders = ('A:'.$mylastcol);
    foreach my $range (@columnheaders){
        $Sheet->Columns($range)->AutoFit();
    }
```

Comment: first, can you check, that you `Find` what you want before use it?  `$Sheet->UsedRange->Find({...})`<- you sure, that this object exists?

Comment: Right curly is missing in your code sample.  Very painful to see.  Please add it. (I could just add it but I assume there might be actually other code missing as well)

Comment: Also the `in` keyword in the main loop opening looks suspicious.  Unless you're using a module extending Perl (like Moose), it would be invalid.

Comment: @loldop:find usually finds the used range right?

Comment: @Alois Mahdal:Actually that was huge code so i kept here only the problematic part.so curly brace is doesn't matter just assume everything is clear!

Comment: Well I understand but anyway as a troubleshooting technique I'd strongly recommend to create and paste here a *working* example of code that exposes the unwanted behavior. By working towards such example you get three things: A) you confirm the assumption that the rest is clear B) you give us a piece we can test ourselves and C) we get rid of the missing curly

Comment: @ Alois Mahdal:hey not like that yar thecode is qite lengthy...and also i thought this code is sufficient!if you want i can give...no probe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote a Perl script to convert a set of CSV files into spreadsheet format using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. After some research I came to conclusion that there is no option to fix column width as Auto-fit option.

Autofit is a runtime option in Excel and so it isn't possible to create it via the file format using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

However, the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel docs contain [an example of how to simulate autofit](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_autofit.pl) with an explanation of some of the issues involved.